# Constructing vectors of different lengths

Tags: matlab, indexing, signal-processing

I want to find out `row` and `column` number of zeros in 3 dimensional space. Problem is I get output vectors(e.g row) of different length each time, hence dimension error occurs. 
My attempt:

```
a (:,:,1)= [1 2 0; 2 0 1; 0 0 2]
a (:,:,2) = [0 2 8; 2 1 0; 0 0 0]

for i = 1 : 2
[row(:,i) colum(:,i)] = find(a(:,:,i)==0);
end
```

Comment: using cell to store the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linear indexing:

```
a (:,:,1) = [1 2 0; 2 0 1; 0 0 2];
a (:,:,2) = [0 2 8; 2 1 0; 0 0 0];

% Answer in linear indexing
idx = find(a == 0);

% Transforms linear indexing in rows-columns-3rd dimension
[rows , cols , third] = ind2sub(size(a) ,idx)
```

More on the topic can be found in [Matlab's help](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html)

Comment: It worked well. Although making cell would be much useful.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "making cell". Making `rows`, `cols` and `third` in a single cell? In three separate cell arrays? A single matrix of cells?

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your Matrix has the format N-by-M-by-P.
In your case

```
N = 3;
M = 3;
P = 2;
```

This would mean that the maximum length of rows and coloms from your search (if all entries are zero) is `N*M=9`

So one possible solution would be

```
%alloc output
row=zeros(size(a,1)*size(a,2),size(a,3));
colum=row;
%loop over third dimension
n=size(a,3);
for i = 1 : n 
    [row_t colum_t] = find(a(:,:,i)==0); 
    %copy your current result depending on it's length
    row(1:length(row_t),i)=row_t;
    colum(1:length(colum_t),i)=colum_t;
end
```

However, when you past the result to the next function / script you have to keep in mind to operate on the non-zero elements.

I would go for the vectorized solution of Zep. As for bigger matrices `a` it is more memory efficient and I am sure it must be way faster.